# Python-generated multi-batch SQL scripts fail due to whitespace

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a list of 10 files that contain views alter scripts of the form

```
ALTER VIEW [Database].[dbo].[ViewName]
AS
SELECT ...
FROM ...
```

I want to deploy all of these scripts simultaneously, so I've written a simple Python script to concatenate them with a "GO" between each statement, like this:

```
ALTER VIEW [Database].[dbo].[ViewName1]
AS
SELECT ...
FROM ...

GO

ALTER VIEW [Database].[dbo].[ViewName2]
AS
SELECT ...
FROM ...
```

When I run this script with SQL Server Management Studio, I get errors like:

1. `Incorrect syntax near ''.`
2. `Incorrect syntax: 'ALTER VIEW' must be the only statement in the batch.`

Etc. I got the same results using cat/echo from the git shell.

It appears to me that there is some whitespace that is causing these issues, but when I edit the script in Notepad++ the whitespace looks fine. All newlines are CR/LF, as is the Windows style, and there are no unprintable characters.

What am I missing here? I would really like to be able to take a list of SQL scripts with ALTER statements, join them with "GO" as separators, and execute all of the statements in one giant script. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but I get the error message "'CREATE/ALTER VIEW' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name."

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what happened to my comment but the idea is to wrap your alter statements in a transactions so that multiple batches can be executed, like so:

```
begin transaction

ALTER VIEW [Database].[dbo].[ViewName1]
AS
SELECT ...
FROM ...

GO

ALTER VIEW [Database].[dbo].[ViewName2]
AS
SELECT ...
FROM ...

GO

commit transaction
go
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue. The script I provided is "valid" SSMS script and actually works if typed out by hand. The issue is with concatenating files automatically due to some problem with (apparently) whitespace.

Comment: @Jake, this solution is specific to the error #2 that you are reporting. Only one alter statement is allowed in a batch and so if you want to run multiple batches, you need a transaction.

Comment: Anand, that is false. You need the GO statements but not a transaction to comply with MS SQL in SSMS. And in any case, the transaction statements don't fix the problem for me.